# Fetching data from server to iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, apache, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I am working on videos application where my videos are available on apache server that has link such as **192.1.58.1/3434** something. The link contain mp4 files like a.mp4, b.mp4, c.mp4. when you click these linke it load video in browser. my question is that How do I get these link into my iphone application. I tried lot but didn't find solution.Please help me out.

Comment: What did you try ? Post some code

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"here is my http://192.12.1.232:2323 link"]];
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",newStr); Actual link is different . But I just want to give you overview of what I tried.

Comment: Probably would be better if you edited your question, put your code in there and format it properly. That way it is easier to read and you will get more help. Anyway: why do you transform your data into a string if the data actually represents a video?

Comment: Ok I will go with only data.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `UIWebView` into your `UIViewController` (I called mine `myWebView`).  Then, in the your `UIViewController` implementation file, add this into your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString* myServerString = @"http://192.1.58.1";
    NSURL* myServerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myServerString];
    NSURLRequest* myRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myServerURL];
    [self.myWebView  loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```